# using azure cli, vmss json template doesn't create vmss with datadisk

Tags: azure, azure-storage, disk

**Context:**
Trying to create VMs in Azure (cloud) using VMSS in ARM mode and using json templates.

**Problem:**
Creating a VMSS from an os image and datadisk image using Azure CLI and json template creates new VMSS but not the datadisk.

**My success so far:**
Successfully created VMs using CLI with both os and data disk from a custom image using json template. Also successfully created VMSS (Virtual Machine Scale Set) from a valid custom os image using CLI with json template.

**My research for problem:**
There isn't any sample on github for this scenario [git hub templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/). Microsoft azure site also have sample for os disk only and not creating a VMSS with data disk.

blkid comand doesn't show the data disk at all, meaning it was never created and mounted. My json template virtualMachineProfile->storageProfile declares a valid dataDisks object and I know it's works as it successfully creates VM (not VMSS) with data disk and also CLI doesn't return any error.

I know json based template is new and Microsoft is working on adding more features/functionalities so my questions is "Is there anything wrong that I am doing and is it that creating VMSS with data disk is not yet implemented in Azure ?"

Environment: Linux (Debian/RHEL)

Azure CLI : 0.9.13 (ARM mode)

Azure Api: 2015-06-15

Image: (CentOS 6.7)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can the one who down voted please let me know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this blog post [VMSS and data disks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arsen/archive/2015/12/30/linux-azure-vm-scale-sets-with-shared-storage-using-lustre.aspx), it is not yet supported. Such a bummer..... Hopefully Microsoft will soon release this feature before selling VMSS too much.

Comment: Data disks are on the VMSS roadmap.